# how to access values in a tag and p tag, here number of "list-group-item-action" will be dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="list-group-item-action"  >
    <a href="link1"> Deve</a>
     <p>Deve Category.</p>
</div>

<div class="list-group-item-action"  >
    <a href="link2">Deve2 </a>
     <p>Software development life cycle (SDLC) </p>
</div>

<div class="list-group-item-action"  >
    <a href="link3"> dev</a>
     <p>Software development life cycle </p>
</div>
```

New to js and jquery plz help

Requirement:-

```
Take values from a and p tag in such a way
Deve
Deve Caetgory
Deve2
software development life cycle
----
----
```

and it should be get downloaded plain/text format.
Here i can make functionality for printing but how can I append all value to one string by taking them from tags

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Where is the functionality of printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use loop using `div` class like below.

```js
$('.list-group-item-action').each(function (index, element) {
var aText = $(this).find('a').text();
var pText = $(this).find('p').text();
console.log(aText);
console.log(pText);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group-item-action"  >
    <a href="link1"> Deve</a>
     <p>Deve Category.</p>
</div>

<div class="list-group-item-action"  >
    <a href="link2">Deve2 </a>
     <p>Software development life cycle (SDLC) </p>
</div>

<div class="list-group-item-action"  >
    <a href="link3"> dev</a>
     <p>Software development life cycle </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the needed loop can be done as follows:

```
var result = '';
$('.list-group-item-action').each(function() {
    result += '\n' + $(this).find('a').html();
    result += '\n' + $(this).find('p').html();    
});
$('#result').val(result);
```

You can see the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/8d06f7y4/